# Maximal proper subgroups of $S_5$

Tags: permutations, finite-groups

Denote by $Sym(X)$ the symmetric group of any set $X$, and let $S_5=Sym(\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5 \rbrace)$. Let $F$ denote the "Frobenius" subgroup $ \langle (1,2,3,4,5) ,(2,3,5,4)\rangle$ (it is a semi-direct product $ \langle (1,2,3,4,5) \rangle\rtimes \langle(2,3,5,4) \rangle$ and has therefore order $20$) and let $P$ denote the "product" group $ Sym(\lbrace 1,2 \rbrace) \times  Sym(\lbrace 3,4,5 \rbrace)$, and $S=Sym(\lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace)$. I wish to show the following :

**Fact.** Let $G$ be a subgroup of $S_5$. Then either $G=S_5, G=A_5$, or $G$ is included in a conjugate of $F$, $P$ or $S$.

**My question:** Find an elementary proof of this fact.

(I have verified this fact using a computer system and now I'm looking for a computer-free proof. I am also aware of advanced results like the O'Nan-Scott theorem but I'm looking for a more elementary proof here).

So far, I was able to show the fact when $G$ contains both a $5$-cycle and a $4$-cycle. Indeed, using conjugation we may assume that $G$ contains $\theta=(1,2,3,4,5)$.

Now, if we put $\alpha=(2,3,5,4),\beta=(2,3,4,5)$ and $\gamma=(2,4,3,5)$, the following table show that every $4$-cycle can be uniquely written as $\theta^k \sigma \theta ^{-k}$ where $\sigma\in\lbrace \alpha^{\pm 1},\beta^{\pm 1},\gamma^{\pm 1} \rbrace$  :

$$
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
k & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\theta^k \alpha \theta ^{-k} & (2,3,5,4) & (1,5,3,4) & (1,4,5,2) & (1,3,2,5) & (1,2,4,3) \\
\hline
\theta^k \alpha^{-1} \theta ^{-k} & (2,4,5,3) & (1,4,3,5) & (1,2,5,4) & (1,5,2,3) & (1,3,4,2) \\
\hline
\theta^k \beta \theta ^{-k} & (2,3,4,5) & (1,3,4,5) & (1,2,4,5) & (1,2,3,5) & (1,2,3,4) \\
\hline
\theta^k \beta^{-1} \theta ^{-k} & (2,5,4,3) & (1,5,4,3) & (1,5,4,2) & (1,5,3,2) & (1,4,3,2) \\
\hline
\theta^k \gamma \theta ^{-k} & (2,4,3,5) & (1,3,5,4) & (1,5,2,4) & (1,3,5,2) & (1,3,2,4) \\
\hline
\theta^k \gamma^{-1} \theta ^{-k} & (2,5,3,4) & (1,4,5,3) & (1,4,2,5) & (1,2,5,3) & (1,4,2,3) \\
\hline
\end{array}\tag{1}
$$

If we define $A(\sigma)=\lbrace \theta^k \sigma \theta ^{-k}\rbrace$ and  $B(\sigma)=A(\sigma)\cup A(\sigma^{-1})$, the table (1) above shows that $B(\alpha) \cup B(\beta) \cup B(\gamma) $ partitions the $4$-cycles. Now, by construction we have that $\langle\theta,\sigma'\rangle =\langle\theta,\sigma\rangle $ if $\sigma'\in B(\sigma)$.

As a first special case, we have $\langle\theta,\sigma\rangle =\langle \theta,\alpha\rangle  = F$ for every $\sigma\in B(\alpha)$.
we similarly have $\langle \theta,\sigma\rangle =\langle \theta,\beta\rangle $ for every $\sigma\in B(\beta)$ and $\langle \theta,\sigma\rangle =\langle \theta,\gamma\rangle $ for every $\sigma\in B(\gamma)$. Now, from $\gamma = \theta^2 \beta^2\theta \beta$ and $\beta = \theta \gamma \theta^2 \gamma ^2$ we see that $\langle \theta,\beta\rangle $ and $\langle \theta,\gamma\rangle $ are the same subgroup of $S_5$. This subgroup contains both $(1,2,3,4,5)=\theta$ and $(1,2)=\beta \theta ^{-1}$, and it is then easy to show that it is the whole of $S_5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how much this can be streamlined. Starting out with the following.

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $S_5$.

**Observation #1.** If $G$ is not transitive, then it preserves a partition of the type 1+4 or of the type 2+3, and the full stabilizers of such partitioins were explicitly listed.

So from this point on we can assume that $G$ is transitive, hence its order is divisible by five, and it contains a 5-cycle $\alpha$.

**Observation #2.** If $3\mid |G|$ then $A_5\le G$.

**Proof.** In this case $G$ contains a 3-cycle $\beta$. The five conjugates
$\alpha^i\beta\alpha^{-i}$ are all 3-cycles, each with two fixed points. It follows easily that among them we have two conjugate 3-cycles sharing exactly one fixed point $a\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. The stabilizer $G_a$ is thus a subgroup of $S_4$ that contains at least two 3-cycles $\beta$ and $\beta'$ that are not each others powers. Any such pair of 3-cycles generates a transitive subgroup of $S_4$, which thus has order at least twelve, and must contain $A_4$. So $G_a$ contains a copy of $A_4$, and the claim follows.

The remaining case is that $3\nmid |G|$. This means that the point stabilizers $G_a$ are 2-groups, and hence are subgroups of an appropriate copy of the dihedral group $D_4\le Stab_{S_5}(a)$. If $G_a$ contains a 2-cycle $\gamma$, then the 2-cycles $\alpha^i\gamma\alpha^{-i}$ generate all of $S_5$, a case already excluded. So if $|G_a|=2$, we know that $G_a$ is generated by a product of two disjoint 2-cycles. Such a permutation is the square of a 4-cycle. At this point I want to eliminate the possibility that $G_a$ contains two distinct permutations with cycle type $(2,2)$. Here we need to be more specific to do calculations with permutations. Without loss of generality $a=1$, $\alpha=(12345)$, and in the case to be eliminated $G_a$ contains at least two (and hence the third as their product) of the permutations $(23)(45)$, $(24)(35)$, $(25)(34)$. Conjugating all of these by $\alpha$ shows that $G$ contains all of $(12)(34)$, $(13)(24)$ and $(14)(23)$. As a product we then find a 3-cycle in $G$. For example $(14)(23)(23)(45)=(14)(45)=(145)$. Again taking us back to a case we already covered. We have shown:

**Observation 3.** If $G$ is transitive and $3\nmid |G|$, then the point stabilizers $G_a$ are all cyclic 2-groups of order $1,2$ or $4$, and cannot contain a 2-cycle.

If $|G_a|=2$, then $G$ must be the dihedral group $D_5$, and those are contained in a conjugate of $F$. The remaining case is $|G_a|=4$. In this case $|G|=20$, so its Sylow $5$-subgroup $P=\langle\alpha\rangle$ is normal. Hence $G_a\le N_{S_5}(P)$. There are $24$ 5-cycles in $S_5$, so $P$ has six conjugates in $S_5$ (each containing four 5-cycles, namely the non-trivial powers of $\alpha)$. It follows that $|N_{S_5}(P)|=120/6=20$, so $G=N_{S_5}(P)$ which is a conjugate of $F$.

Comment: Gotta commute next. Hopefully this can be simplified.